# Why is $\underline{F}$ the Fréchet derivative of $\underline{F} : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

The questions asks what the Fréchet derivative of $F : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is. The solution states that by inspection of the definition of the Fréchet derivative, $D\underline{F}(\underline{x}+\underline{h}) - \underline{F}(\underline{x}) + r = \underline{F}(\underline{h}) + r$ (since $\underline{F}$ is linear) where $r \in o(\underline{h})$. Then taking $\underline{h}$ as $h\underline{v}$ with $|\underline{v}| = 1$ and $h \rightarrow 0$ in $\mathbb{R}$, see that $D\underline{F}(\underline{x})$ and $\underline{F}$ coincide for all vectors $\underline{v}$, hence $D\underline{F}(\underline{x}) = \underline{F}$. 
I don't understand the part about taking $\underline{h}$ to be of that form and how it shows that they are equal. I'm assuming it somehow relates to the fact that Fréchet derivatives are always linear maps, but I'm exactly sure how this would be relevant.

Comment: And $F$ is...?${}$

Comment: The function. I realise I was not consistent with the notation, apologies.

Comment: what is $r$? {} {}

Comment: I don't know, it was just stated in the solutions

Comment: The question is "Why $f$ linear $\implies$ $Df(x)=f$?"?

Comment: My confusion is with everything really. I don't understand the solution at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "let $h=hv$" seems to be inconsistent notation so we will let $h=mv$ where $v$ is a unit vector. Now:

$DF(x+mv)-F(x)+r=F(mv)+r$

$\Rightarrow DF(x+mv)=F(mv)+F(x)=F(x+mv)$

now take $m\to 0$ to get:

$DF(x)=F(x)$